# Adding toolbar to a ViewController in storyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, uitoolbar, segue

I'm using storyboard to create an iPad app. On the main view I have a toolbar and a bar button item, let's call it "show". Then I have dragged a table view controller into the storyboard. I have also added a subclass of UITableViewController to the files and made the class of the dragged table view controller to be that subclass. And I made a popover segue from the "show" button to the table view controller. It works fine, meaning that when "show" pressed I see the popover showing the correct data that I set in the table view. What I cannot seem to figure out is how to put a toolbar on top of the table view in the popover. I took a step back and used a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController and still cannot add a toolbar by dragging it to the view. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up putting the TableViewController within a NavigationController and the latter in a PopoverController, all in the code, without using IB. I found this an easier solution to get the toolbar than anything else that might work.